# .net core not able to read object out of appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, config

My dotnetcore application has a problem reading this object out of the appsettings.json:

```
  "image": {
    "ImagePresets": {
      "SearchListing"    : {"Width": 415, "Height": 220, "Fit": true},
      "PropertyPage"     : {"Width": 650, "Height": 350, "Fit": true},
      "Large"            : {"Width": 910, "Height": 650, "Fit": true},
      "FeaturedLocation" : {"Width": 272, "Height": 296, "Fit": true}
    }
  },
```

here is the object I'm trying to deserialize it to:

```
public class ImagePresets
{
    public Preset SearchListing { get; set; }
    public Preset PropertyPage { get; set; }
    public Preset Large { get; set; }
    public Preset FeaturedLocation { get; set; }

    public ImagePresets()
    {
        FeaturedLocation = SearchListing = Large = PropertyPage = new Preset();
    }

}
    public class Preset
{
    int Width { get; set; }
    int Height { get; set; }
    bool Fit { get; set; }
}
```

and this is how I am trying to read it:

```
ImagePresets _presets = _config.GetSection("image:ImagePresets").Get<ImagePresets>();
```

When I try executing `_config.GetSection("image:ImagePresets").GetChildren()` I do get the KeyValuePairs, but deserializing always returns empty values like:

```
Fit [bool]:
false
Height [int]:
0
Width [int]:
0
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't `.Get<ImagePresets>()` take care of the deserialization?

Comment: The settings contain strings, not integers. You can't deserialize a string into an integer property. In JSON, `"345"` and `"true"` are just strings. You need to remove the quotes

Comment: I tried removing the quotes from both the numeric properties and the boolean one, didn't help. Even set the properties in the object as strings got me the same result.

Comment: Have you tried making the properties in Preset public?  I don't think the Binder will handle private properties.

Comment: Also remove constructor `ImagePresets`. Or at least remove from it the assignment of the same instance of the class to properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply because the properties of `Preset` is not public. This works

```
public class Preset
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public bool Fit { get; set; }
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern):

> An options class:
>
> - Must be non-abstract with a public parameterless constructor.
> - All **public read-write properties of the type are bound.**

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, You get get values like following code:

```
public class ClassName{

    public ClassName(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    YourClass YourMethod() {
        return Configuration["image:ImagePresets:SearchListing"];
    }
}
```